# Dynamically deploying content scripts in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to deploy content scripts only into sites that a user wants to deploy them to. I have this list of sites, and I want to deploy some script.js only to these sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this (in a background page):

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.status == "complete" && isInUserList(tab.url)) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file:"script.js"}, function() {
            //script injected
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that you need the [`tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) permission to be able to access `tab.url`.